# Create sf bounding box from four lat/long coordinates

Tags: r, gis

I have two dataframes in R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(nelat = c(35.0, 35.2, 33.1, 32.0),
                  nelng = c(-106.8, -109.5, -110.6, -109.0),
                  swlat = c(33.7, 34.8, 32.7, 31.5),
                  swlng = c(-106.9, -109.9, -110.9, -109.3))
> df1
  nelat  nelng swlat  swlng
1  35.0 -106.8  33.7 -106.9
2  35.2 -109.5  34.8 -109.9
3  33.1 -110.6  32.7 -110.9
4  32.0 -109.0  31.5 -109.3

df2 <- data.frame(snake = c("rattlesnake", "ratsnake", "cobra", "cobra", "python"),
                  lat = c(33.8, 36.0, 32.1, 33.0, 30.3),
                  lng = c(-106.8, -110.0, -110.7, -109.1, -110.1))

> df2
        snake  lat    lng
1 rattlesnake 33.8 -106.8
2    ratsnake 36.0 -110.0
3       cobra 32.1 -110.7
4       cobra 33.0 -109.1
5      python 30.3 -110.1
```

I want to combine the four coordinates from df1 into an sf object (a bounding box/rectangle, essentially) for each row.

I tried the below code but got an error.

```
    df1_sf <- df1 %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("swlng", "swlat", "nelng", "nelat"), 
               crs = 4326)
```

The error says "Error in points_rcpp(as.matrix(cc), dim) :
dim(pts)[2] == nchar(gdim) is not TRUE"

My end goal is to count how many snakes from df2 are in each df1 rectangle.

Comment: You are trying to pass too many points to `st_as_sf()`  since it only expects one latitude and one longitude at a time to create a POINT geometry list column. My recommendation is to split your data frame, convert each half to `sf` objects, and then use those to create a bounding box, e.g., 
`df1_ne_sf <- df1 |>
  dplyr::select(nelat, nelng) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("nelng", "nelat"), crs = 4326)`

Comment: A box would need 2 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that you should create `POLYGON` object with `st_polygon()`. Here at least 5 points are needed. I write `f()` function to create them with your rows in `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
df1 <- data.frame(nelat = c(35.0, 35.2, 33.1, 32.0),
                  nelng = c(-106.8, -109.5, -110.6, -109.0),
                  swlat = c(33.7, 34.8, 32.7, 31.5),
                  swlng = c(-106.9, -109.9, -110.9, -109.3))

df2 <- data.frame(snake = c("rattlesnake", "ratsnake", "cobra", "cobra", "python"),
                  lat = c(33.8, 36.0, 32.1, 33.0, 30.3),
                  lng = c(-106.8, -110.0, -110.7, -109.1, -110.1))

# convert points in each row to polygon
f <- function(nelat, nelng, swlat, swlng){
  m <- matrix(c(swlng, nelng, nelng, swlng, swlng,
                swlat, swlat, nelat, nelat, swlat), nrow = 5)
  return(st_polygon(list(m)))
}

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(geometry = list(f(nelat, nelng, swlat, swlng))) %>%
  st_as_sf(sf_column_name = "geometry") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = lng, y = lat))
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. It seems like there could be a bespoke function for this in sf, maybe I'll do a feature request.